# Newbie Render Question

Tags: modeling, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm having trouble rendering this object and was wondering if anyone would mind taking a look. For some reason whenever I go to render it the vertex on each end seem to distort and the lines on my outline layer are really thick for some reason and then taper off... Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It seems like a very straightforward model. Apologies if this is a super newbie question.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]